# How come the instance of my object is missing the properties I want to assign?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsobject

I am trying to create a class in with properties defined in the header. Was planning to populate the object in a for loop. Here is the header, what could I be doing wrong? Am I defining this class wrong?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDataSource, 
...
@end

@interface PickerObject : NSObject
{
    NSString *minutes;
    NSNumber *label;
}
@end
```

In the viewDidLoad I get message saying property minutes not found.

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int x = 0; x < total; x++)
{
    PickerObject *myObject = [[PickerObject alloc] init];
    myObject.minutes = x;
    myObject.label = @"%@ minutes",x;

    [_pickerData addObject:myObject];

    //[_pickerData addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:x]];
    [arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:x]];
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the error depicting property not found

[image]

Comment: That's because you don't have a minutes property. You have a minutes instance variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access object variables using the dot '.' operator in Objective-C, you need a setter method. The easiest way to achieve this is by defining a property instead, like this:

```
@interface PickerObject : NSObject
{

}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *minutes;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *label;

@end
```

The object variables, setter- and getter methods you need will be synthesised automatically.